# How to solve the equation $x^3+y^3=0$ for real numbers $x$ and $y$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, roots

I'm finding stationary points of the function $f(x,y)=2(x-y)^2-x^4-y^4$, but stuck in the equation $x^3+y^3=0$ while solving the equations $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $x=0\iff y=0$  else $(x/y)^3=-1$ the only real value of $x/y$ is $-1$

Comment: $x^3+y^3=0$$\iff$$x^3=-y^3$$\iff$$(x)^3=(-y)^3$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanks I got your point. How can i show only real number satisfies the equation $ x^3= -1$?

Comment: Thank you so much to all who gave answer and comment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: 
 Notice, $$x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2+y^2-xy)$$ Then, we have $$(x+y)(x^2+y^2-xy)=0$$

Comment: So, either $ x+y=0$ or $x^2+y^2-xy=0$ that is $ y=-x $ but what about 2nd equation?

Comment: I want to know how $x^2+y^2-xy=0$ implies $x=0, y=0$? Give me some hint regarding this.

Comment: Alright, you see $x^2+y^2$ is always positive & equal to the product of $x$ & $y$. Thus $xy$ will be positive only when $x=0$ & $y=0$  for real values of $x$ & $y$ because $x$ & $y$ are opposite in sign by first equality $x+y=0$ or $y=-x$

Answer (score 1):

Starting with $x^3+y^3=0$, we have $$x^3 = -y^3 =(-y)^3$$ so $$x=-y$$ since cubing is a one-to-one function. Indeed, the line $x=-y$ is the solution set to the equation $x^3+y^3=0$